# qtree with fullstop

Tags: linguistics, tikz-qtree, qtree

I want to draw a constituent tree for a sentence ending with a full stop, but this gives errors in qtree. This is the example without a full stop. Now I want to add a full stop to the end, which is connected with the root node S.

```
\begin{figure}
\Tree [.S [.NP LaTeX ] [.VP [.V is ] [.NP fun ] ] ]
\end{figure}
```

Can this be done with qtree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\Tree [.S [.NP LaTeX ] [.VP [.V is ] [.NP fun ] ] {.} ]
```

with **`qtree`**

[image]

or with **`tikz-qtree`**

[image]

Or maybe better

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=90pt},level distance=30pt}
\Tree [.S [.NP LaTeX ] [.VP [.V is ] [.NP fun ] ] [.\node[shape=coordinate,yshift=1ex]{}; {.} ] ]
\end{document}
```

[image]